# Synchronized Block takes more time after instrumenting with ASM

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to instrument java synchronized block using ASM. The problem is that after instrumenting, the execution time of the synchronized block takes more time. Here it increases from 2 msecs to 200 msecs on Linux box.

I am implementing this by identifying the MonitorEnter and MonitorExit opcode.

I try to instrument at three level 1. just before the MonitorEnter 2. after MonitorEnter 3. Before MonitorExit.
1 and 3 together works fine, but when i do 2, the execution time increase dramatically.

Even if we instrument another single SOP statement, which is intended to be executed just once, it give higher values.
Here the sample code (prime number, 10 loops):

```
for(int w=0;w<10;w++){
synchronized(s){
  long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
  long num = 2000;
for (long i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        long p = i;
    int j;
    for (j = 2; j < p; j++) {
            long n = p % i;
        }
    }
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
 System.out.println("Time>>>>>>>>>>>> " + (t2-t1) );
}
```

Here the code for instrumention (here System.currentMilliSeconds() gives the time at which instrumention happened, its no the measure of execution time, the excecution time is from obove SOP statement):

```
  public void visitInsn(int opcode)
    {
        switch(opcode)
        {
          // Scenario 1
        case 194: 
            visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io   /PrintStream;");
            visitLdcInsn("TIME Arrive: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
            visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
            break;

        // scenario 3
        case 195: 
            visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            visitLdcInsn("TIME exit : "+System.currentTimeMillis());
            visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
            break;
        }

        super.visitInsn(opcode);

       // scenario 2
       if(opcode==194)
        {
            visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            visitLdcInsn("TIME enter: "+System.currentTimeMillis());
            visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");

        }

        }
```

I am not able to find the reason why it is happening and how t correct it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not measuring the synchronization itself as both `currentTimeMillis` invocations are within the synchronized block. By the way, what is `s`? What knowledge about the contention happening when synchronizing on that object do you have?

Comment: **s** is a String object upon which sync is done. here i am only using a single thread, and the sync block runs 10 time. Every time (t2-t1) time is calculated. I am using the currentTimeMillis inside the block bcoz it is the service time of this block wich is same for all thread. This is my motive, that why it is increasing so much after instrumentation. Please donot consider the contention part right now. Atleast the execution time should remain the same.

Comment: You are measuring the JVMs ability to optimize away unused/nonsense code and it seems that adding a print statement (which effect is visible from the outside) at a certain place disturbs the optimizations. By the way, a `String` is an unusual object to sync on. Not really recommended.

Comment: My intention is to call a function that take timestamps at the three levels and then by subtraction i could calculate the arrival time, waiting time for the lock  for a particular thread. Earliar i have a funtion which took timestamps at those levels, but it increases the execution time. Thats why i put SOPs. But could u tell me how could i see what optimizations JVM is doing. And BTW the SOP or function call is outside the "for loop", how is it affecting the optimization. Any solution to this.

Comment: Please Answer this: More Over if i directly put SOP statement at the entrance of sync block in the .java file and then run it, the execution time remains the same. Why it is increasing if i do this by instrumentation.

Comment: The optimizer will process blocks of code so your SOP might influence it or not. It’s very likely that a SOP before `monitorenter` or after `monitorexit` have no influence as these are natural boundaries but you can’t even rely on that as the JVM might try to optimize the sync itself as well. There’s a simple thing to remind: *instrumentation influences timing*. And the smaller the time to measure (and you are hunting for very small intervals) the bigger the problem will become. So don’t do it; use the JVMs builtin monitoring capabilities.

Comment: Just Try to do this: `   sychronized(s){ System.out.println("Entered"); \*everything else remains the same there*\  ` Write the SOP directly in java file and then write through instrumentation. Compare the timings.

Comment: Why should I do this? I already told you that instrumentation influences timing. The optimizer is beyond your control. You will have to accept this fact. You may find a reason if you investigate long enough but it won’t help you. A tiny change in the next release of the JVM and you will have the same problems again.

Comment: Ok. So the optimization is at compile time or runtime? Any Article suggestions if u could provide.

Comment: At runtime. The keywords are “JIT” and “Hotspot optimizer”

Answer (score 1):

The reason lies in the internals of the JVM that you were using for running the code. I assume that this was a HotSpot JVM but the answers below are equally right for most other implementations.

If you trigger the following code:

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  result += i;
}
```

This will be translated directly into Java byte code by the Java compiler but **at run time** the JVM will easily see that this code is not doing anything. Executing this code will have no effect on the outside (application) world, so why should the JVM execute it? This consideration is exactly what compiler optimization does for you.

If you however trigger the following code:

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  System.out.println(result);
}
```

the Java runtime cannot optimize away your code anymore. The whole loop must always run since the `System.out.println(int)` method is always doing something *real* such that your code will run slower.

Now let's look at your example. In your first example, you basically write this code:

```
synchronized(s) {
   // do nothing useful
}
```

This entire code block can easily be removed by the Java run time. This means: **There will be no synchronization!** In the second example, you are writing this instead:

```
synchronized(s) {
   long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
   // do nothing useful
   long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
   System.out.println("Time>>>>>>>>>>>> " + (t2-t1));
}
```

This means that the effective code might be look like this:

```
synchronized(s) {
   long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
   long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
   System.out.println("Time>>>>>>>>>>>> " + (t2-t1));
}
```

What is important here is that this optimized code will **be effectively synchronized** what is an important difference with respect to execution time. Basically, you are measuring the time it costs to synchronize something (and even that might be optimized away after a couple of runs if the JVM realized that the `s` is not locked elsewhere in your code (buzzword: temporary optimization with the possibility of *deoptimization* if loaded code in the future will also synchronize on `s`).

You should really read this:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp02225/
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp12214/

Your test for example misses a warm-up, such that you are also measuring how much time the JVM will use for byte code to machine code optimization.

On a side note: Synchronizing on a `String` is almost always a bad idea. Your strings might be or might not be [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) what means that you cannot be absolutely sure about their identity. This means, that synchronization might or might not work and you might even inflict synchronization of other parts of your code.